# jetty test example "not found"

Tags: java, jetty

I downloaded jetty and immediately started it up `java -jar start.jar` When I then browse to http://localhost:8080/test, it fails to work.

I see there's a warning that it cannot "reuse..", but I don't understand what the message is saying. Can anyone help me make sense of the warning:

> 2011-06-27
>   15:53:05.724:INFO::jetty-8.0.0.M3
>   2011-06-27
>   15:53:05.739:INFO::Deployment monitor
>   C:\Users\joslim\Documents\Projects\XML-RPC
>   PoC\jetty\webapps at interval 1
>   2011-06-27
>   15:53:05.755:INFO::Deployment monitor
>   C:\Users\joslim\Documents\Projects\XML-RPC
>   PoC\jetty\contexts at interval 1
>   2011-06-27
>   15:53:05.755:INFO::Deployable added:
>   C:\Users\joslim\Documents\Projects\XML-RPC
>   PoC\jetty\contexts\test.xml
>   **2011-06-27 15:53:05.849:WARN::Can't reuse
>   C:\Users\joslim\AppData\Local\Temp\jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-test.war-*-any-,
>   using
>   C:\Users\joslim\AppData\Local\Temp\jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-test.war-*-any-*7021813664435934609***   2011-06-27 15:53:05.849:INFO::Extract
>   jar:file:/C:/Users/joslim/Documents/Projects/XML-RPC%20PoC/jetty/webapps/test.war!/
>   to
>   C:\Users\joslim\AppData\Local\Temp\jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-test.war--any-*7021813664435934609\webapp
>   2011-06-27 15:53:06.395:INFO::started
>   o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/,file:/C:/Users/joslim/AppData/Local/Temp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-test.war-*-any-_7021813664435934609/webapp/},C:\Users\joslim\Documents\Projects\XML-RPC
>   PoC\jetty/webapps/test.war
>   2011-06-27
>   15:53:06.660:INFO:org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.TransparentProxy:TransparentProxy
>   @ /javadoc to
>   http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/apidocs
>   2011-06-27
>   15:53:06.660:INFO::Deployable added:
>   C:\Users\joslim\Documents\Projects\XML-RPC
>   PoC\jetty\contexts\javadoc.xml
>   2011-06-27 15:53:06.675:INFO::Started
>   SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
>   STARTING

Answer (score 1):

Try `http://127.0.0.1:8080/`. Beacause "contextPath" value is "/" in contexts/test.xml by default.

Answer (score 0):

Try seeing if the war is bound to the root at http://localhost:8080/

or if it is bound as http://localhost:8080/test.war

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me if I used `http://127.0.0.1:8080/`.

If I use `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1`, it doesn't work.